# Как создать множество окон веб браузера и получить доступ к объектам javascript из основной программы на C#?

Tags: c#, node.js, webbrowser

Как создать множество окон веб браузера и получить доступ к объектам javascript внутри окон(либо фреймов)?
Суть- есть сервис, выполняющий определённые вычисления, но что б задействовать всю мощь- надо держать открытыми 100-150 вкладок браузера и одновременно их мониторить на определённые изменения в браузере. Соответственно нужно открыть в веб браузере определённые страницы-получить к ним рут доступ и когда там произойдут события- уведомлять основную программу. А само окно браузера можно не отображать для экономии ресурсов. Интересует только внедрение во внутрь кода запускаемых сотни страниц из программы на C#(лучше) ну или Nodejs.

Comment: Pазмещаете COM-обьект браузера InternetExplorer.Application в окне приложения, у обьекта есть script обьект и дальше получаете доступ. Можно добрасывать скрипты через `Navigate("javascript:your_code;")` Назад в c# можно через Eval.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome совсем недавно зарелизили специальный безголовый режим браузера, т.е. запускается полноценный браузер, но без UI. Параллельно с этим они сделали хорошую nodejs либу для работы с таким браузером - [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

Вот небольшой пример (больше примеров в readme)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');

  // Get the "viewport" of the page, as reported by the page.
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    return {
      width: document.documentElement.clientWidth,
      height: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
      deviceScaleFactor: window.devicePixelRatio
    };
  });

  await browser.close();
})();
```